# Not getting dict back from mysql.connector in flask app

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am porting a flask app from SQLite to MySQL. I have the following in my app.py:

```
def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    con = get_db()
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query, args)

    result = cur.fetchall()

    cur.close()

    return (result[0] if result else None) if one else result

@app.route("/")
def index():

    rows = query_db("SELECT * FROM computers")

    return render_template("index.html", rows = rows)
```

In the console I get:

```
('FE:CB:40:50:B9:04', '192.168.11.163', 'Jules - Desktop (iMac)', None, 0, Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, None, None, None, 1, 0, 0, None, None, 0, 0, '', 1, 1571097594)
```

In my template I have:

```
{% for row in rows %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{row['reboots']}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Consequently, when I try to render my template I get:

```
`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'tuple object' has no attribute 'reboots'`
```

...where `reboots` is a field in the database. I didn't change the schema before migrating to MySQL so I expect the templates to work as-is. Do I need to cast the result as a dict or something?

Comment: "I don't think I am getting tuples back at all" Why would you think that? You are clearly getting a tuple back (actually a list or tuple of tuples). The error you get clearly says it

Comment: You're right. It does clearly indicate that I am getting a tuple back. Still, why is mysql.connector returning something different for MySQL? I'll add some template code for additional context.